# Membership.CreateUser: The E-mail supplied is invalid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser("jfewfewa801","r09gtrez30@")

Above statement return "The E-mail supplied is invalid." until I set
requiresUniqueEmail="false" in web.config. Is there a way to create
user with empty email address while required non-empty email to be
unique?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create user with empty email address while required non-empty email to be unique?

Not possible without you handling this with some custom code, but i wouldn't recommend it :

you could have users(plural!) with no email defined in the database

So at the end several users with the same mail(empty or null)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider** as the provider?

The path of the method calls might look like this (starts from calling the **CreateUser** method which receives only two parameters from the object **System.Web.Security.Membership**):
[image]

If yes then this logic inside the method CreateUser of **System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider** could be the cause:

```
...
if (!SecUtility.ValidateParameter(ref email, this.RequiresUniqueEmail, this.RequiresUniqueEmail, false, 0x100))
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail;
            return null;
        }
...
```

The ValidateParameter works this way:

```
internal static bool ValidateParameter(ref string param, bool checkForNull, bool checkIfEmpty, bool checkForCommas, int maxSize)
    {
        if (param == null)
        {
            return !checkForNull;
        }
        param = param.Trim();
        return ((!checkIfEmpty || (param.Length >= 1)) ? (((maxSize <= 0) || (param.Length <= maxSize)) && (!checkForCommas || !param.Contains(","))) : false);
    }
```

ValidateParameters returns **False** when the email (param) is null and the "requiresUniqueEmail" (checkForNull) is TRUE.

The ! in **if (!SecUtility.ValidateParameter(ref email, this.RequiresUniqueEmail, this.RequiresUniqueEmail, false, 0x100))** will then evaluate to be TRUE ( ! False ) and the logic returns *NULL* instead of executing the below SQL command to create user *(dbo.aspnet_Membership_CreateUser)* in that SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser method.

I am using .net 4.7.1 in answering this.